# Microsoft OLEDB Provider for SQL , DateTime2 is added as DateTime

Tags: sql-server, delphi, sql-server-2012

I am using SSL from now on so I moved from the integrated SQL OLEDB (MDAC) to the **Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server**.

And I was hoping that suddenly `datetime2(7)` would work. But unfortunately I only get `datetime` back, and the Nanoseconds are gone. Is this expected?

Example: `2022-03-11 07:39:53.86286`

Delphi with MSOLEDBSQL19.1 2022-03-11 07:39:59  ( .86286 is not present )

I used `FormatDateTime('dd.MM.yyyy hh:nn:ss.zzzzz',ADOQuery1Lastmodzeit.Value)`

`11.03.2022 07:39:53.862`, but still wonder why the 86 is cut off.

So now at least I have something.

Even though ADOQUERY returns `datetime2(5)` as `datetime`. If I set the displayproperty of ADOQUERY Field to dd.mm.yyyy HH:nn:ss.zzzzz then I get the same 11.03.2022 07:39:53.862. Now I only wonder why is the rest cut off?

Comment: This should not be a driver issue, because a driver not supporting `DATETIME2` has the result of giving you back strings when querying a `DATETIME2` column, not `DATETIME` -- and even `DATETIME` has more precision than seconds. It may be an issue of how Delphi fetches the results, though.

Comment: Are you using ADO? Like the SQL drivers that ship with windows, ADO is unaware of data types introduced since SQL Server 2000.

Comment: sorry I forgot. Yes I am using ADO. But I am not using the Integrated deprecated Drivers! I am using the latest Microsoft SQL OLEDB Drivers . Which are undeprecated.

Comment: The legacy ADO technology knows nothing of newer SQL data types, like `datetime2`.

Comment: @DanGuzman : Dan , I am not using the legacy ADO Drivers , those gave back WideString for DateTime2 , I am using the new Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: ADO _is_ a legacy driver, and it's also a wrapper for OleDb.  You've updated the underlying OleDb provider, but the old ADO layer is still old.

Comment: Adding to what David said, ADO is an API, not a driver.